# how do you add a conditional type on the return of a function where the return values are related?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to wrap my head around the following. I have a function:

```
export const useProject = (id: string) => {
  <project fetching logic here>

  return {
    project,
    loading: project === undefined
  }
}
```

basically if a project exists, `loading` is false, otherwise `project` is undefined.

my issue is that with this code:

```
const { project, loading } = useProject(id)

if (loading) return 'loading…'

return project.title
```

typescript complains that `project` could be undefined at the final return. How can I update the function so that typescript knows `project` exists in the case that `loading` is `false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that even if you represent the return value of `useProject()` as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) where the `loading` property can be used to determine if the `project` property is defined,  the TypeScript compiler won't be able to follow the correlation between the subproperties once you copy them into separate `project` and `loading` variables.

That is, you could refine the typing of your `useProject()` like this:

```
export const useProject = (id: string) => {
    const project = Math.random() < 0.5 ? ({ title: "hey" } as Project) : undefined;
    return {
        project,
        loading: project === undefined
    } as { project: Project, loading: false } | { project: undefined, loading: true };
}
```

but the following code will still give you an error:

```
const { project, loading } = useProject("zoop")
if (loading) return 'loading…'
return project.title; // error! Object is possibly undefined
```

If you want the compiler to understand that checking `loading` has an implication for the type of `project`, you'll need to refer to them as properties of a common parent discriminated union object:

```
const projStatus = useProject("zoop");
if (projStatus.loading) return 'loading…';
return projStatus.project.title; // okay
```

---

(UPDATED FOR TS4.4)

There were a few issues in GitHub where it's been suggested that the compiler should perform such control-flow based narrowing on properties or other type guard checks that have been copied to other variables, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#12184](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12184) and [microsoft/TypeScript#24865](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24865).  These have been addressed by [microsoft/TypeScript#44730](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44730) which will be released with TS4.4.  But even this doesn't work for multiple correlated variables like `project` and `loading`:

> In particular, the pattern of destructuring a discriminant property and a payload property into two local variables and expecting a coupling between the two is not supported as the control flow analyzer.

So for now this is still a limitation of TypeScript.

---

If you can refactor your code to discriminated unions that you don't destructure, great.  Otherwise you'll need to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) or the equivalent to silence the compiler's warning:

```
return project!.title; // okay, using non-null assertion
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYCsILMgbwFgAoZc5MYMAGwgC5kBnMKUAcwG5SBfU0iAA8ADhij4EGEC2QBXJhHTZc+ALzIAFMAAmjFmxDsAlMlUA+QqQrJJ0-MMw48p5AFk4YABYA6KHBDaGAC2GiYAPMgADN4ArMgA-JoElNR0jABEnhAAnunIPMhwTGiOKiaMsgEQMKAQ2txkFFAQYLJQIJaN1uQOyngANFbd5DQYcNocjL1OaqrqldrVtdpD5AVFhMjTKoxKM-3Io+OTyPA0CvnIAD6b23gVVTUgdQdHE4aMrLIoPA18JKQYJU8MApMgAEZwKChTrWWwyaYAZTAHnkLnkilKeA06QAXhgMMJ0kYGtZgDBNEiUa0mN43hwTM1Wu1kAByemGQBkBKzSU0Wm0OlTUbS7mBvFRaBBOMgAPQy5AYADWcGyvH4JCBIBBYJgBJhxC6NikMmSoteY3e7Eu8wUexUOPxhOJq2Q5M0HOMyCZArZHu5Lu9LNFAEJxakpbL5UqVQd5BxkCApABaECyGg0QpMBTiUEgNUkIA)